# PowerShell: my ConfigFile that is succesfully written has gone away as soon as the script ends?

Tags: file, powershell

my script stores key values in a hash, so that the line with those keyes are not treated again.
Each time a new key is stored the has is saved:

```
function readConf($File) {

    $H = @{}

    if (test-path -path $File) { 

        Get-Content $File | ForEach-Object { 

            $x = $_ -replace "-", ""

            $x = $x -replace "Name", ""

            $x = $x -replace "Value", ""

            $x = $x.Trim()

            $L = $x -split "\s{3,}"

            #echo(" ok: "+$L+"
            $H[ $L[0] ] = $L[1]

            $H.Neu = Get-Date  -uformat "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"    

        } 

    }

    $H

}

hConf = readConf($confFile) # no problem so far"

...

while ($true) {

...

if ( $hConf[$key] ) { continue }

$hConf[$key] = $val

$hConf > $confFile
...

} # end of endless while
```

As long as this script is running I can see and open this configFile,
everything is there, what should be there.
But as soon as I stop the script (by Ctrl-c or in the ISE click on the red button)
my configfile is gone, it just disapeared??
Other files that were written the same time line by line still exist?

Of course I check that I don't have e file-delete, but even if I would store an empty hash 
by what ever reason, I think I see an empty file - but the Config-File is gone?

Does anybody know a reson for that?
Thanks in advance,
gooly

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite following what you're trying to do, but:

```
$hConf > $confFile
```

doesn't look right. You probably want:

```
$hConf >> $confFile
```

or

```
$hConf | out-file -append $conffile
```

-Oisin